# How to open .jpg file with Minimagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

I have an error with MiniMagick during my "after_upload" in my image_concern.rb

My code makes the image that is poster be converted to jpg. Then it will take the file which is in / tmp and will modify this file to have it also in smaller to display it for later. But I have an error during this step:

```
`mogrify -resize 360x200^ -gravity Center -crop 360x200+0+0 /tmp/RackMultipart20200211-5215-1lxtqf1.png` failed with error: mogrify: unable to open image '/tmp/RackMultipart20200211-5215-1lxtqf1.png':
```

It tries to open this file in .png but it is in jpg in my tmp /. How to say that it opens this file but not in png but in jpg. Thank you
This is my after_upload code:

```
def #{field}_after_upload
          path = #{field}_path
          options = #{options}
          if #{field}_file.respond_to? :path
            dir = File.dirname(path)
            FileUtils.mkdir_p(dir) unless Dir.exist?(dir)
            image = MiniMagick::Image.new(#{field}_file.path) do |b|
              if options[:resize].ends_with?('!')
                b.resize '#{options[:resize].delete('!')}^'
                b.gravity 'Center'
                b.crop '#{options[:resize].delete('!')}+0+0'
              else
                b.resize '#{options[:resize].delete('!')}\>'
              end
            end
            image.format 'jpg'
            image.write path
            if options[:formats]
              options[:formats].each do |k, v|
                image = MiniMagick::Image.new(#{field}_file.path) do |b|
                  b.resize "\#{v}^"
                  b.gravity 'Center'
                  b.crop "\#{v}+0+0"
                end
                image.format 'jpg'
                image.write path.gsub('.jpg', "_\#{k}.jpg")
              end
            end
          end
        end
```

The bug starts from "if options[:formats]"

Thank you !

Comment: you want to resize image?

Comment: He want to open rackmultipart.....png but in my tmp its .jpg. So i want to open the .jpg not de .png
When he do that 
if options[:formats]
              options[:formats].each do |k, v|
                image = MiniMagick::Image.new(#{field}_file.path) do |b|
                  ....
                end

Comment: Don't know much, but why don't you try carrierwave gem instead? If you need help about carrierwave, I will try my best.